# Alignment in ST_Intersection with PostGIS raster

Tags: postgis, raster, intersection, alignment

Trying to intersect two rasters, but they don't have the same scale. I have to do everything in one query.

The query below gets the following error: `The two rasters provided do not have the same alignment`

```
select row_to_json(t) from (
    SELECT A.rid, B.rid, pvc
    FROM file_xbwnbydpmwesokzmrcht A 
    JOIN file_caolvkddzzlgmvyeofrh B 
    ON ST_Intersects(A.rast, B.rast), 
       ST_ValueCount(ST_Intersection(A.rast,1, B.rast, 1)) AS pvc
) as t;
```

I've tried this, but syntax is wrong, apparently (`ERROR:  column a.rast does not exist`):

```
select row_to_json(t) from (
    SELECT A.rid, B.rid, pvc
    FROM (
        select st_rescale(
            C.rast, st_scalex(D.rast)
        ) from file_caolvkddzzlgmvyeofrh as C CROSS JOIN file_xbwnbydpmwesokzmrcht as D
    ) as A
    JOIN file_caolvkddzzlgmvyeofrh B 
    ON ST_Intersects(A.rast, B.rast), 
       ST_ValueCount(ST_Intersection(A.rast,1, B.rast, 1)) AS pvc
) as t;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I think you need to alias the function call ST_Rescale(....) as rast, as this is what a.rast will be referring to. At the moment, it will have the alias st_rescale.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBarça. Could you provide a full example from what I have above?